# How to point to a file in a different folder on iOS/iPadOS?

Tags: ios, ipados, symlink, alias, files.app

On my iPad, I use iCloud Drive and the Files app. My files are organized in folders in iCloud Drive so that I can access them on all of my devices.

I frequently want to point to a file that is stored in a different folder.

For example, I have four folders in iCloud Drive that I access via the Files app on iPad. I would like to have a reference/pointer to the same file (e.g., a PDF) in all of those four folders.

Having copies of the file in different folders causes redundancy and it needs space. When I update the file, I have to update it in all folders.

On macOS, I can create a symbolic link or an alias for such purposes. I believe that this is not possible on iOS and iPadOS.

I‘m aware of tags and favorites. However, they are global and I don‘t want to clutter these with files I need only in certain projects. They also cannot be organized hierarchically like folders and subfolders.

So, what is the best way to point to a file in a different folder without having a copy of that file?

Although symlinks and aliases are not supported by iPadOS, I am looking for creative ideas to deal with this shortcoming.

Comment: Can you describe the use case? Are you working in Files.app and do some operations on files? Do you want to have quick access in "file picker" from different app?

Comment: I have added more information regarding the use case

Comment: Especially for projects, tags with the project name would work quite well.

Comment: Yes, for a few projects. However, I have many and I organize my projects in folders and subfolders, i.e., I make use of a hierarchy. Hierarchies are very well suited to manage complexity and to get a structure. Tags cannot be hierarchically organized. „Thus my central theme is that complexity frequently takes the form of hierarchy and that hierarchic systems have some common properties independent of their specific content. Hierarchy, I shall argue, is one of the central structural schemes that the architect of complexity uses.“
From The Sciences of the Artificial by Herbert Simon

Comment: Someone downvoted this question. It would be really helpful if people who downvote would leave a constructive comment that tells me what should be improved. Only downvoting is not very constructive. I saw that on AskDifferent, people vote up rarely but quickly down. In my opinion this is not a constructive and motivating environment.

Comment: @vomako - I see you've experienced what I call the "down vote horde."  Don't let it get to you.  Your question is actually a good one...the answer though.... +1 for the question!

Comment: Based on experience, focused questions work better than broad ones, and questions listing potential solutions lead to answers commenting on those instead of actually providing answers (there even is a "close" reasons related to this: "This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers").

Comment: Do the apps you use on the iPad allow you to put their files into a directory you choose, or do they "insist" on storing them in one app-specific directory?

Comment: Well, I find the question to be quite narrow since it addresses a very specific need I have. The list of possible solutions was necessary in my opinion so that people understand better what I want (since it is clear to me that the Files app neither supports symlinks nor aliases). I‘m not asking for opinions but for ideas to solve my problem.

Comment: I think that almost all the important apps I use allow to store their files in a directory I choose. I organize all my files in folders on iCloud Drive.

Comment: @nohillside On a related note, as you are a moderator, I think that downvote should not be anonymous and they should require a reason, both enforced by StackExchange. But maybe this is a discussion for meta.

Comment: Voting is anonymous (even to moderators) for good reasons. The "downvote with a comment" discussion has come up on Meta (both on [AD](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1693/downvoting-etiquette-with-or-without-making-a-comment) and [overall](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)), and the general opinion seems to be that downvote comments can't be enforced. Also, if you look at [the purpose of comments](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment), "explaining downvotes" is not one of the reasons.

Comment: Also, I‘m not questioning your intentions. But based on past experience with AD, questions listening ideas and options instead of focusing on the problem to be solved tend to attract bad answers and downvotes.

Comment: @nohillside I have now moved my ideas for a solution into an answer. However, I think that it can make sense to provide such ideas for solutions in the question since it shows that the person asking has done his or her research and thought about it.  It is actually recommended on SO to state what has been tried and what research has been done. I think this should definitely not be a reason to downvote a question. Downvoting a question, especially without leaving a comment, is a pretty aggressive move.

Comment: The „what have you tried and researched“ rule is also valid for AD. Don‘t know the detailed rules on SO but IMHO untried ideas and thoughts are not the same as things one has tried. But anyway, you got one downvote, this happens to all of us now and then.

Answer (score 1):

> ... what is the best way to point to a file in a different folder without copying the file on iPadOS and iOS?

To paraphrase Steve Jobs, "[You're doing it wrong!](https://www.cnn.com/2010/TECH/mobile/06/25/iphone.problems.response/index.html#:%7E:text=You%27re%20holding%20it%20wrong.%20%22Just%20avoid%20holding%20it,known%20to%20occasionally%20answer%20e-mails%20from%20customers%20himself.)"  That's not meant as a dig, but more of a facetious way to approach this question.

#### Everything should be done via iCloud (or another cloud service)

You shouldn't be trying to create symlinks and/or manage what file is where when iCloud Drive was designed to do exactly this.  If you enable *[iCloud Desktop and Documents](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985)* always select the file using iCloud (found in the sidebar).  This way, any changes you make will be automatically synced with the cloud and you won't have to worry about symlinks and copies upon copies of the same file.

While iCloud is great, I have opted for [Microsoft OneDrive](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/onedrive/online-cloud-storage).  It provides a better mechanism for creating my folder hierarchy and configuring which folders I would like to sync and which ones I don't.

[image: OneDrive Preferences]

In your sidebar, you have all the locations from which to access files.  Instead of linking things from point A to B to C and copies made in two or three different places, always access the file via your cloud service.   Below are screen grabs from both my Mac sidebar and from my iPad Files App of where you should be storing your files for centralized access:

[image: Cloud Services in Sidebar] [image: iPad Locations Selector]

In my setup, I have my Documents folder completely sync'd with OneDrive.  Therefore, whether I choose to navigate through OneDrive (locations) or directly through Documents, the file is always the same one.  One feature of OneDrive that I particularly like is the ability to send a link to the file rather than the file itself.  If I send a Word or Excel file to be reviewed, for example, the recipient will get a link and open the file *on my OneDrive account*.  Any changes made will be saved there and they won't have to email me back a different version of the file.

It may take a little exploring around and experimenting with what you want and don't want synchronized, once you take the perspecitive of the cloud being the center from which you operate, you'll find that it works substantially better than all the symlinking you were looking to do.

Comment: This answer seem to have misunderstood the question completely - he's asking for a solution on an _iPad_. You're giving him a solution for the Mac, which he states he already has.

Comment: @jksoegaard - it works on iPad too.  This is exactly how I keep my Mac, Windows machine, iPad, iPhone, and even the rogue Android tablet I have all synced up.

Comment: That's all good - but it doesn't address the question at all. You're talking about having the same file duplicated on computers, tablets and various cloud services - that's not what this question is about.

Comment: @jksoegaard, you must have missed the whole theme of the answer:  "You're doing it wrong."

Comment: No, I have not missed that. I'm saying that your "theme" misses the point. You're answering a different question than what was asked. He's saying that he's using an iPad and he's using iCloud Drive. Imagine that he's using those exclusively. The point of your answer doesn't apply now. What he wants to do is to essentially "store" the same file multiple times in the file hierarchy without having it take up lots of extra space, and without the burden of having to update the copies seperately.

Comment: I.e. a typical example in the work place would be having a folder structure with a folder for each client, and below that a folder for each project. Each project has a set of unique files. However, you might have one file that is reused amongst many projects - you want to place that into each project's folder so that if you make external copies of the project, or want to re-familiarize yourself with the project after time, you remember and know that this file is part of the project -- however you would prefer that it doesn't take up extra space every time. [...]

Comment: This can be handled with links on a desktop computer - however it is not that easy on an iPad running iPad OS.

Comment: Allan, thanks for the answer. I updated my question to avoid the misunderstanding of the last sentence that may have led to your answer.

Comment: I understand what both of you are saying.  You'd like to access the files in different places on iCloud.  Bottom line, iCloud is not geared for that and in fact, handles it horribly.  OneDrive while it won't handle what you want to do perfectly will better allow you to do what you want via it's web interface and the way it works with macOS.  So, the short and blunt answer to your question is "it's not possible."  I instead gave you a solution that *would* work.

Comment: jksoegaard, thank you, everything you wrote is correct.
Allan, sorry for the wording of the last sentence. That could have been misunderstood. I have changed it. Thanks anyway for taking the effort to answer the question.

Comment: @vomako - Unfortunately, you either have to copy the file or change your workflow.  Cloud services require folks to change to effectively utilize the service.

Comment: @Allan: Yes, I see what you are saying. Symlinks and aliases work well on a single computer but not in a distributed environment because not all files are available on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

- For a small number of projects (or something similar), tags are feasible, where the tag name may be equal to the project name (thanks „nohillside“)
- For many folders, one could have *one* folder where all the original files for all projects are stored. Then, in a project folder, one would have a text document with the name of the file, which serves as a pointer. With this approach, one would not even have to store the full path but only the name of the file (since all original full-size files are in *one and the same* folder). This would work but it is cumbersome since one cannot just click on the text document to open the original file.

I‘m looking for other creative ideas that are less limited or cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the equivalent of creating a macOS symlink, alias and or shortcut, for an iPad.

I've been looking for ways of doing this on my iPhone for years.

This is what I've found for the iPhone. It should be the same for the iPad too.

*To jump to the best method I’ve found, see option 3 below in Other Methods of Achieving Similar Functionality. I highly recommend trying one of the two apps I listed before discounting as not a possible solution.*

**Natively, the short answer:**

- There is no native way of doing this in iCloud Drive or the Files app as of right now (*iOS 16.5.1*).

There are other ways of achieving similar functionality though. The best method I’ve found is by using a 3rd party app, see option 3 below.

**Other Methods of Achieving Similar Functionality**

1. **Shortcuts (possible native solution)**

   - You could build a shortcut in the Shortcuts app to imitate the functionality. It’d be a relatively complex shortcut that may or may not be worth the effort. I’ve been making shortcuts since Apple first released the app and personally I decided it wasn’t worth the effort myself.
2. **Scriptable (3rd party)**

   - You could use JavaScript in the Scriptable app to build a solution that imitates the functionality, similar to option 1. Scriptable also integrates with the Shortcuts app too. I haven't looked into this option too much because I don't know enough about JavaScript. This is probably a better way to go than using shortcuts alone (option 1).
3. **3rd Party File Management Apps (Best option)**

   - 3rd party apps exist that have features which are basically the equivalent of an alias on MacOS. Each app calls the feature something different (such as "virtual folders" or "file linking", "connections", etc.). In my experience this as close to the functionality as you’re looking for, if not exactly what you’re looking for.
   - The way it works, depending on the app, is you can point a connection to a folder stored anywhere in iCloud Drive and then go from there by adding more connections pointing to other files & folders.
   - Here are two free apps I've found which allow you to add files & folders pointed or linked to other files & folders. There are other apps which offer more features, but these are free so you can try them and get an idea of how it works.

     - [FileBrowseGo](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/filebrowsergo/id335493278)
     - [Owl Files](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/owlfiles-file-manager/id510282524)