# To access a file from arbitrary folder

Tags: mac, ipad, icloud

I have many Pages documents in different folders on my Mac and sometimes I need to edit them on an iPad. I tried to use iCloud for this, but it seems iCloud requires me to move them to the iCloud folder first, and this isn't convenient to me (that is, I want to keep them in their original folders instead).

Is it possible to access them from both devices via iCloud without moving them from their original folders?

Comment: If you don’t put the in a folder that syncs with the cloud, how are you supposed to access them via the cloud?  You need to [restructure your workflow](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/454262/119271) so this works properly for you.

Comment: @Allan I have just read your answer you have linked and the [respective Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985), but I still don't understand. It seems that if I want to edit them on both devices, I have two options: either 1. keep all these files in the iCloud folder (no other folders there, just files), or 2. re-create on iCloud a hierarchy of folders that I use on my Mac, right?

Comment: Basically yes. If you want to access files from several devices, they need to be in iCloud (or in any other cloud storage/sync solution).

Comment: What @nohillside said.  If you want to access via iCloud, they need to be in the cloud service’s folder(s)

Comment: I am somewhat puzzled with “iCloud folder”.  Maybe it’s “Drive”? You can sync [Documents and Desktop](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985) with iCloud.

Comment: Yes, this folder is actually called "iCloud Drive".